# How to make svg line responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have made this svg diagram http://jsfiddle.net/F3wPz/2/show/ and have tried expressing the shapes in it in percentages http://jsfiddle.net/F3wPz/2/

However,while the rectangles are respond to resize,the lines aren't.For instance,in this line

```
<line id="svg_3" y2="55" x2="447" y1="55" x1="168" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
```

i am hesitating to think that the start of line and end of line on the x and y axis can be expressed in percentages since they are th eonly ones not resizing on screen resize.Is it wrong to express the lines in `%`?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those x and y values are not pixel units, they're expressed in units that are relative to the SVG's coordinate system. If your SVG is sized using relative units (e.g., `%` or `em`) then the line should scale accordingly without you having to modify any `line` attributes. I think what you're missing for this to work is the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute on your `<svg>` element.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/F3wPz/3/) showing your SVG at 50% scale.

Relevant code section:

```
 <svg width="50%" height="50%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
```

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to express the line co-ordinates in percentages.

Answer (score 2):

http://meloncholy.com/blog/making-responsive-svg-graphs/

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g>
...
</g>
</svg>
```